# ¿Cómo utilizar el export y el import entre hojas de Javascript si en ellas tengo el evento addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, importación, javascript-import, module.exports

En un proyecto que estoy realizando quisiera utilizar las funciones de export e import de Javascript pero no me funcionan...

Tengo dos hojas de Javascript.

En una tengo el siguiente arreglo que quiero exportar a la otra hoja javascript

```
export const usuarios = [
    {
        nombre: "Juan",
        apellido: "Perez",
        user: "juanperez",
        pass: "54321",
        saldo: 3000000
    },
    {
        nombre: "Santiago",
        apellido: "Misas",
        user: "misas_mouse",
        pass: "2468",
        saldo: 2500000
    },
    {
        nombre: "Andrea",
        apellido: "Roldan",
        user: "AndreaRoldan",
        pass: "2468",
        saldo: 2300000
    }
   
];
```

y entre otras muchas cosas, tengo este evento en un evento dentro de esta hoja

```
     btnIniciar.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        
        });
```

Obviamente adentro tiene acciones a penas se le de click a un boton, pero no son relevantes considero yo para esta pregunta.

Ahora, en la hoja 2 de javascript le hago import de la hoja 1 y deseo mostrar un dato de una posición especifica con un document querySelector

```
import {usuarios } from "./hojaUno.js";
document.querySelector('#titulo-bienvenida').textContent="Bienvenido "+usuarios[1].nombre;
```

pero al hacer esto me sale el siguiente error que no entiendo:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'addEventListener')
> at

Yo solo necesito un elmento específico de la hoja javascript no que se me ejecute un addEventListener si importo algún elemento.
Ya el script module está agregado en los html.

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: Hola, esas importaciones siempre las hice poniendo el listener en el archivo main.
el archivo que vas a importar dejalo sin listener, el codigo que deberia ir adentro del listener, escribilo como funcion. En el archivo main, llamas al archivo que tiene la funcion, declaras un listener, y dentro del listener llamas a la funcion

Comment: Hola Carlos. Hice lo  que me dijiste y me funcionó. Con esto me ayudaste a comprender que todos aquellas hojas que tengan un callback no se le deben exportar elementos ya que no funcionará; y que antes bien, si quiero exportar elementos o funciones, deben estar en otra hoja de javascript. Gracias!